# Deleting words from a string and printing their addresses

Tags: c++

The task is to delete all repeating words from the string and then print the addresses of these words (meaning the addresses of the first letters) in the original string on the screen.

My code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string inputString = "cactus word programmer cat word dog cat. cat mug words.";
    inputString += ' ';
    string copiedString = inputString;
    string word;
    int wordSize = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < copiedString.size(); i++)
    {
        if (copiedString[i] == ' ' || copiedString[i] == '.')
        {
            //startIndex = i;
            word.insert(0, copiedString, startIndex, wordSize);
            while (copiedString.find(' ' + word + ' ', startIndex + wordSize) != -1 || 
                   copiedString.find(' ' + word + '.', startIndex + wordSize) != -1)
            {
                string *address = (inputString.find(word, startIndex + wordSize) + &inputString);
                cout << *address << '\t' << address << endl;
                copiedString.erase(copiedString.find(word, startIndex + wordSize), wordSize + 1);
            }
            while (copiedString.find(' ' + ' ') != -1)
            {
                copiedString.erase(copiedString.find(' ' + ' ', 1));
            }
            word.clear();
            wordSize = 0;
            startIndex = i + 1;
        }
        else
            wordSize++;
    }

    cout << inputString << endl;
    cout << copiedString << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So I tried to make it work with both dots and spaces. For that I needed a loop which deletes all
unnecessary spaces (the second while loop). The program doesn't delete spaces, however, and throws some exceptions saying I'm trying to access wrong part of the memory (I think) and it prints incorrect addresses (last 2 repeat for some reason).

Comment: I am *certain* `copiedString.find(' ' + ' ')` isn't doing what you think it is, primarily because `' ' + ' '` isn't synonymous with . And even after it is fixed, `-1` is the wrong test result. `std::string::npos` is the test value for not-found on a find search. Further `(inputString.find(word, startIndex + wordSize) + &inputString);` is death. That creates an utterly invalid `std::string*` that is simultaneously wrong and non-dereferencable. This almost looks like a C implementation where `char` buffers and pointers with replaced with `std::string` and `std::string*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up rewriting the whole thing but this is what I came up with:

```
int main()
{
    string inputString = "cactus. word programmer cat word dog cat. cat. cat mug words. words. abc abcde abba programmer";
    inputString = inputString + ' ';
    string copiedString = inputString;
    string word;
    int wordSize = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < copiedString.size(); i++)
    {
        if (copiedString[i] == ' ' || copiedString[i] == '.')
        {
            word.insert(0, copiedString, startIndex, wordSize);
            int k = 0;
            while (copiedString.find(' ' + word + ' ', startIndex + wordSize) != -1)
            {
                const size_t currentIndex = inputString.find(' ' + word + ' ', startIndex + wordSize);

                cout << word;
                if (wordSize >= 7)
                    cout << '\t';
                else
                    cout << "\t\t";

                cout << (inputString.find(' ' + word + ' ', currentIndex + k * wordSize) + &inputString) << endl;
                copiedString.erase(copiedString.find(' ' + word + ' ', startIndex + wordSize), wordSize + 1);
                k++;
            }
            k = 0;
            while (copiedString.find(' ' + word + '.', startIndex + wordSize) != -1)
            {
                const size_t currentIndex = inputString.find(' ' + word + '.', startIndex + wordSize);

                cout << word;
                if (wordSize >= 7)
                    cout << '\t';
                else
                    cout << "\t\t";
                

                cout << (inputString.find(' ' + word + '.', currentIndex + k * wordSize) + &inputString) << endl;
                copiedString.erase(copiedString.find(' ' + word + '.', startIndex + wordSize), wordSize + 2);
                k++;
            }
            word.clear();
            wordSize = 0;
            startIndex = i + 1;
        }
        else
            wordSize++;
    }

    cout << endl << inputString << endl;
    cout << copiedString << endl;

    return 0;
}
```